# Ayuda base de datos Android Studio

Tags: android, base-de-datos, sqlite

Estoy haciendo una App de preguntas test, en la cual deben salir 30 preguntas con sus posibles respuestas marcables en el mismo layout. Mis dudas son cuando debo crear base de datos. He creado la carpeta res-->raw donde guardo las preguntas y respuestas de la siguiente manera:

```
pregunta1;opcionBuena;opcionmala1;opcionmala2;img1
pregunta2;opcionBuena;opcionmala1;opcionmala2;img2
etc..
```

Ahora siguiendo tutoriales y ejemplos he creado las clases DBContract:

```
public class DBContract {

public static abstract class TestEntry implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME ="bdTest";
    public static final String PREGUNTA = "pregunta";
    public static final String CORRECT_ANSWER = "correctAnswer";
    public static final String DISTRACTOR1 = "distractor1";
    public static final String DISTRACTOR2 = "distractor2";
    public static final String IMAGEN = "imagen";
   }
}
```

Y DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BBDD.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBContract.TestEntry.TABLE_NAME+ "("
            + DBContract.TestEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
            + DBContract.TestEntry.PREGUNTA + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + DBContract.TestEntry.CORRECT_ANSWER + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + DBContract.TestEntry.DISTRACTOR1 + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + DBContract.TestEntry.DISTRACTOR2 + "TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + DBContract.TestEntry.IMAGEN + "TEXT )");
    lecturaBaseDatos(sqLiteDatabase);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

private ArrayList<Question> lecturaBaseDatos(SQLiteDatabase s) {
    ArrayList<Question> test = new ArrayList<Question>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DBContract.TestEntry.TABLE_NAME,null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            test.add(new Question(
                    c.getString(1),
                    c.getString(2),
                    c.getString(3),
                    c.getString(4),
                    c.getString(5)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return test;
   }
}
```

Dispongo tambien de una clase Test() que es un listado de la clase Question() la cual forma la pregunta completa con sus respuestas.

Es la primera vez que hago base de datos y se que esta mal implementado pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo bien, sobretodo el metodo lecturaBaseDatos que lo he adaptado respecto a un ejemplo encontrado.

Tambien quisiera saber como deberia llamar mostrar la lista de test en la Actividad que muestra los tests.

Gracias.